# C++ private function member

Tags: c++

I learned that if I declare data members or function members in a class without access modifier the compiler treats them as private members, now I have a simple class called `showNum` and when I run the program it gives me a different value from what I entered!
Is that because `set_value` function is private and it's not accessible from the object `num1` that's why it gives me another value?

The codes of class `showNum` and `main` function are:

```
class showNum
{
    int a;
    void set_value(int num)
    {
        num=5;
        a=num;
    }
public:
    void show_value()
    {cout<<a;}
};

void main()
{
    showNum num1;
    num1.show_value();
}
```

Comment: Where do you set the value?

Comment: You never call `set_value` so `a` is never set to anything.

Comment: What do you expect this to output? Also you are missing a return type for `main`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never call set_value() so your member `a` is uninitialized when you call show_value () and so `a` will be undefined

Comment: when I call set_value function the compiler gives me an error :
error: void showNum::set_value(int)' is private

Comment: @mouad_raizada Of course you get a compiler error, because `set_value()` is `private`.

Comment: thanks for the answer , I was confused about my answer and now it's clear

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this:

```
class showNum
{
int a;
public:  //change hear
void set_value(int num)
   {
     //change hear
    a=num;
   }

void show_value()
{cout<<a;}
};
main()
{
showNum num1;
num1.set_value(5);//change hear
num1.show_value();
}
```

Comment: compiler error when calling set_value function in main because it's private